# static files django

Tags: django

Django прекрасно видел static files. После того как поставил `DEBUG = false`, перестал. Они лежат на уровне со всеми приложениями, в папке static. `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` тоже прописан. В чем проблема?

Comment: В том, что раздача статических файлов не входит в задачи Django. Это правильное и описанное в документации поведение

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, а что тогда делать?

Comment: Настраивать web-сервер для обслуживания статики.